# Whatsapp like image choose and add caption

Tags: android, arraylist, imageview, whatsapp

I wants to develop app in which user could choose multiple photos from gallery and can add caption like there is in whatsapp to add captions in multiple images
Anyone can help me in this.

Comment: Did you start the app already? Which part are you stuck at?

Comment: No, actually i searched alot but not able to get anything from the net.

Comment: If you are looking for a guide for an exact app like you need, chances are you won't find one. However, I advise you that you start off by diving your development plan into smaller pieces and then look up how do it piece by piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for this,
[image]

You are on right place,
Here is the full solution I do for helping the beginners :

**Layout UI Design**

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/currentStreamImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selected_photo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/add_image_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fade_in_black"
        android:id="@+id/captionArea"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:hint="@string/enter_caption_here"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    </LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AddImageWithCaptionFragment**

```
public class AddImageWithCaptionFragment extends Fragment implements ImageWithCaptionListener {

private ArrayList<ImgCap> imgCapArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private PerfectAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ImageView select,mainStream;
private EditText captionEt;
private int mCurrentPosition;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_img_with_cap_layout, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    select = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_photo);
    mainStream = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentStreamImage);
    captionEt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.caption);

    select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TedBottomPicker bottomSheetDialogFragment = new TedBottomPicker.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setOnMultiImageSelectedListener(new TedBottomPicker.OnMultiImageSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImagesSelected(ArrayList<Uri> uriList) {

                            imgCapArrayList.clear();
                            for (int i=0;i<uriList.size();i++) {
                                ImgCap imgCap = new ImgCap(i,"", uriList.get(i));
                                imgCapArrayList.add(imgCap);
                            }

                            adapter = new PerfectAdapter(getActivity(),imgCapArrayList,mainStream,AddImageWithCaptionFragment.this);
                            LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    })
                    .setPeekHeight(1600)
                    .showTitle(false)
                    .setCompleteButtonText("Done")
                    .setEmptySelectionText("No Select")
                    .create();

            bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        }
    });

    captionEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            imgCapArrayList.get(mCurrentPosition).setCaption(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void imgCaptionCallBack(int position) {
    mCurrentPosition = position;
    captionEt.setText(imgCapArrayList.get(mCurrentPosition).getCaption());
}
}
```

**Custom Adapter Class**

```
public class PerfectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PerfectAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<ImgCap> imgCapsList;
private ImageView mainStream;
private ImageWithCaptionListener mCallBack;

public PerfectAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ImgCap> imgCapsList,ImageView mainStream,ImageWithCaptionListener mCallBack) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.imgCapsList = imgCapsList;
    this.mainStream = mainStream;
    this.mCallBack = mCallBack;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item_layout, parent, false);
    return  new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    final ImgCap element = imgCapsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    Glide.with(context).load(element.getImagePath()).into(holder.image);
    Glide.with(context).load(imgCapsList.get(0).getImagePath()).into(mainStream);

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Glide.with(context).load(element.getImagePath()).into(mainStream);
            mCallBack.imgCaptionCallBack(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imgCapsList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}
}
```

**Listener Class For CallBack**

```
public interface ImageWithCaptionListener {

void imgCaptionCallBack(int position);

}
```

**Item layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**POJO Class**

```
public class ImgCap {

private int position;
private String caption;
private Uri imagePath;

public ImgCap(int position, String caption, Uri imagePath) {
    this.position = position;
    this.caption = caption;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public Uri getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
}

public void setImagePath(Uri imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}
}
```

Just Copy and Paste , Enjoy !!!

Comment: Its a bit late but still thank you for atleast i got the answer